# Recording a video to file with ios

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios, avcapturesession

I'm trying to find a working sample to record videos with IOS (using xamarin) but there's always something missing or not working for me.
My best try using several forum posts and samples is the following :

```
using System;

using CoreGraphics;
using Foundation;
using UIKit;
using AVFoundation;
using CoreVideo;
using CoreMedia;
using CoreFoundation;
using System.IO;
using AssetsLibrary;

namespace avcaptureframes {
    public partial class AppDelegate : UIApplicationDelegate {
        public static UIImageView ImageView;
        UIViewController vc;
        AVCaptureSession session;


        OutputRecorder outputRecorder;
        DispatchQueue queue;

        public override bool FinishedLaunching (UIApplication application, NSDictionary launchOptions)
        {
            ImageView = new UIImageView (new CGRect (10f, 10f, 200f, 200f));
            ImageView.ContentMode = UIViewContentMode.Top;

            vc = new UIViewController {
                View = ImageView
            };

            window.RootViewController = vc;

            window.MakeKeyAndVisible ();
            window.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Black;

            if (!SetupCaptureSession ())
                window.AddSubview (new UILabel (new CGRect (20f, 20f, 200f, 60f)) {
                    Text = "No input device"
                });

            return true;
        }

        bool SetupCaptureSession ()
        {
            // configure the capture session for low resolution, change this if your code
            // can cope with more data or volume
            session = new AVCaptureSession {
                SessionPreset = AVCaptureSession.PresetMedium
            };



            // create a device input and attach it to the session
            var captureDevice = AVCaptureDevice.DefaultDeviceWithMediaType (AVMediaType.Video);
            if (captureDevice == null) {
                Console.WriteLine ("No captureDevice - this won't work on the simulator, try a physical device");
                return false;
            }
            //Configure for 15 FPS. Note use of LockForConigfuration()/UnlockForConfiguration()
            NSError error = null;
            captureDevice.LockForConfiguration (out error);
            if (error != null) {
                Console.WriteLine (error);
                captureDevice.UnlockForConfiguration ();
                return false;
            }

            if (UIDevice.CurrentDevice.CheckSystemVersion (7, 0))
                captureDevice.ActiveVideoMinFrameDuration = new CMTime (1, 15);
            captureDevice.UnlockForConfiguration ();

            var input = AVCaptureDeviceInput.FromDevice (captureDevice);
            if (input == null) {
                Console.WriteLine ("No input - this won't work on the simulator, try a physical device");
                return false;
            }

            session.AddInput (input);


            // create a VideoDataOutput and add it to the sesion
            var settings = new CVPixelBufferAttributes {
                PixelFormatType = CVPixelFormatType.CV32BGRA
            };
            using (var output = new AVCaptureVideoDataOutput { WeakVideoSettings = settings.Dictionary }) {
                queue = new DispatchQueue ("myQueue");
                outputRecorder = new OutputRecorder ();
                output.SetSampleBufferDelegate (outputRecorder, queue);
                session.AddOutput (output);
            }

            session.StartRunning ();
            return true;
        }

        public override void OnActivated (UIApplication application)
        {
        }

        public class OutputRecorder : AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate
        {
            AVAssetWriter writer=null;
            AVAssetWriterInput writerinput= null;
            CMTime lastSampleTime;
            int frame=0;
            NSUrl url;

            public OutputRecorder()
            {
                string tempFile = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), "NewVideo.mp4");
                if (File.Exists(tempFile)) File.Delete(tempFile);
                url = NSUrl.FromFilename(tempFile);
                NSError assetWriterError;
                writer = new AVAssetWriter(url, AVFileType.Mpeg4, out assetWriterError);
                var outputSettings = new AVVideoSettingsCompressed()
                {
                    Height = 300,
                    Width = 300,
                    Codec = AVVideoCodec.H264,
                    CodecSettings = new AVVideoCodecSettings
                    {
                        AverageBitRate = 1000000
                    }
                };
                writerinput = new AVAssetWriterInput(mediaType: AVMediaType.Video, outputSettings: outputSettings);
                writerinput.ExpectsMediaDataInRealTime = false;
                writer.AddInput(writerinput);
            }

            public override void DidOutputSampleBuffer (AVCaptureOutput captureOutput, CMSampleBuffer sampleBuffer, AVCaptureConnection connection)
            {
                try
                {
                    lastSampleTime = sampleBuffer.PresentationTimeStamp;

                    var image = ImageFromSampleBuffer(sampleBuffer);

                    if (frame == 0)
                    {
                        writer.StartWriting();
                        writer.StartSessionAtSourceTime(lastSampleTime);
                        frame = 1;
                    }
                    String infoString = "";
                    if (writerinput.ReadyForMoreMediaData)
                    {
                        if (!writerinput.AppendSampleBuffer(sampleBuffer))
                        {
                            infoString = "Failed to append sample buffer";
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            infoString = String.Format("{0} frames captured", frame++);
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        infoString = "Writer not ready";
                    }
                    Console.WriteLine(infoString);

                    ImageView.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => ImageView.Image = image);

                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(e);
                }
                finally
                {
                    sampleBuffer.Dispose();
                }
            }

            UIImage ImageFromSampleBuffer (CMSampleBuffer sampleBuffer)
            {
                // Get the CoreVideo image
                using (var pixelBuffer = sampleBuffer.GetImageBuffer () as CVPixelBuffer)
                {
                    // Lock the base address
                    pixelBuffer.Lock (CVOptionFlags.None);
                    // Get the number of bytes per row for the pixel buffer
                    var baseAddress = pixelBuffer.BaseAddress;
                    var bytesPerRow = (int)pixelBuffer.BytesPerRow;
                    var width = (int)pixelBuffer.Width;
                    var height = (int)pixelBuffer.Height;
                    var flags = CGBitmapFlags.PremultipliedFirst | CGBitmapFlags.ByteOrder32Little;
                    // Create a CGImage on the RGB colorspace from the configured parameter above
                    using (var cs = CGColorSpace.CreateDeviceRGB ())
                    {
                        using (var context = new CGBitmapContext (baseAddress, width, height, 8, bytesPerRow, cs, (CGImageAlphaInfo)flags))
                        {
                            using (CGImage cgImage = context.ToImage ())
                            {
                                pixelBuffer.Unlock (CVOptionFlags.None);
                                return UIImage.FromImage (cgImage);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            void TryDispose (IDisposable obj)
            {
                if (obj != null)
                    obj.Dispose ();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This works displaying live camera image and I get "frames captured" message in consol but I don't find how to record to file.

I read somewhere about adding `VideoCapture` but I don't know how to link with my code.
Any help will is welcome.

Comment: look at the Xamarin Media plugin

Comment: I tried and it works but I have no control of the visual style, Can I ?

Comment: If you want to create a visual style. You can try to put some buttons to achieve your effect.

Answer (score 2):

From your code, in the construct of class `OutputRecorder` you have defined the url where you want to save the recording:

```
string tempFile = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), "NewVideo.mp4");
if (File.Exists(tempFile)) File.Delete(tempFile);
url = NSUrl.FromFilename(tempFile);
```

It means you want to save the video in the tmp folder in the app's sandbox. If you want to use the video sometime later, I recommend you to change the folder to documents by using:

```
string filePath = Path.Combine(NSSearchPath.GetDirectories(NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory, NSSearchPathDomain.User)[0], "NewVideo.mp4");
```

I notice that you have called `session.StartRunning();` in the method `bool SetupCaptureSession()` to start recording. please add `session.StopRunning();` to end recording then the video will be saved in the path we just defined above. 
Moreover, you can retrieve the video with the path like:

```
NSData videoData = NSData.FromFile(filePath);
```